# How to fix, Reference no duplicate in mails

Tags: php, wordpress

I am generating reference no in emails, sometimes it duplicate reference no in some mails.

I am using microtime(), getTimestamp() and random generating function in my code. 
I am using WAF cache as my server. 
Note: I can not use database.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

````
function generate_inquiry_reference_no(){
    $date=current_time("Y-m-d");
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $date."-".$randomString;

}

function generate_email_reference_no(){
    $date = new DateTime();
    $email_ref_no=$date->getTimestamp();
    $ref_no = ((microtime() * 100000)*10);

    return $email_ref_no."-".$ref_no;

}```
````

Comment: i wouldn't roll my own when php has a function for it, in this case, uniqid()

Comment: ID was generated. But 2 users are sending request in same page same time, both users had the same reference number.

Comment: @Dinithikakaumini did you manage to get it working with my code below?

Comment: It's Working. But My server has caching issues. Therefor Same times Some malls had same reference no. Now I have changed that requirement using database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using something like `random_bytes` to get an actual random result, rather than one based on the time.

```php
function str_rand(int $length = 64){ // 64 = 32
    $length = ($length < 4) ? 4 : $length;
    return bin2hex(random_bytes(($length-($length%2))/2));
}

echo (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d') . '_' . str_rand(10)
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you for your support. But my server side had caching issues, then I have modified that Using database.